# Trying to understand forks and semaphores

Tags: c, process, fork, semaphore

What I am trying to do in my code is have a parent process that forks two children processes. This is how I've done it:

```
pid = fork();

if(pid != 1)
    pid1 = fork();
```

The next thing I'm trying to do is switch between the processes continuously (from child to other child to parent, in that order) using semaphores. *ie* the child process will  say A, the other child will say B, the parent will say C, the child will say D, and so on.

My two questions are:

- Say you call `sem_wait(sem)` in a semaphore and the process blocks as it should. You then move on and the other process ends up calling `sem_post(sem)`. Will the code following the `sem_wait` be immediately executed after the `sem_post`? *ie* does the execution "jump back" to the code after the `sem_wait` even if it doesn't come "next" in the program?

  ```
  if(stuff){
      a; 
      sem_wait(sem); 
      b;
  }
  c; 

  sem_post(sem);
  ```

Will `b` be executed even though it's "before" the post in terms of coming before it textually?

- How can I identify the processes so that I may give one of them permission to execute? I have to confirm that a process is either child 1 , child 2 or parent before I give it permission to execute the code, but how can I tell? I tried to check using `if` statements (`if(pid) != 0`, `if(pid() == 0` and `if(pid1 == 0)` assuming that the parent would have a return value of 0 for the the first fork and the children would have zero's for their respective forks) but this did not work. I checked their PID's and PPID's and they were all over the place).

All help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: the function: `fork()` can return 2 normal conditions and one error condition.   ==-1 means `fork()` failed.   >0 means in parent process  ==0 means in child process.  One easy way to handle this is following the call to `fork()` with a switch statement `case -1:`// error  `case 0:` // child and `default:` //parent   The code needs to properly handle all three conditions.  Note since 1 is the pid of the `init()` function, a call to `fork()` will never return 1  However, it can return -1

Comment: when a process 'blocks' then the OS will switch to another process that is 'ready to continue'.   However, the next process to run (probably) will not be the other process just created.  This should not concern you at all.  The other child process will be blocked via the call to `semwait()` and when the first child process calls `sempost()` that will allow the second child process to change from 'blocked' to`ready to run' so it will be placed on the execution queue and will run when the OS (eventually) continues its' execution.

Comment: this statement: `if(pid() == 0` is nonsense.  the 'pid' is a `pid_t` variable, not a function.

Comment: strongly suggest reading the man page for `fork()`, as that will clear up most of your questions.

Comment: you might want to read/understand the concept of `context switching` to get a better idea about how things work in the OS.  Suggest google: `context switching`